# Excel & Win 10: Open & close many workbooks at once

Tags: microsoft-excel

We just got this operating system. Previously I had several workbooks that i regularly used together. They are not linked so I can make a change on one that affects the other. They just are separate spreadsheets that I use every day. I wanted them to open at the same time and then close them all with one keystroke. I could do that before with a little icon on the ribbon. I just selected that and it prompted me to save all the changes on all the workbooks and then I could close them at one time. Very easy. Now that button seems to have disappeared of my ribbon. I can't remember what it was called and can't seem to find it on any help sites. Can you help?

Comment: Sounds like you need to add the excel shortcut button back on your ribbon. Click on the windows button, scroll down to excel click and hold and drag it to your ribbon.

Comment: If they are not related (linked) as you say, they will not open or close as a unit. Perhaps show us a screen shot of the button. It may have been a macro.

Answer (score 0):

To open all the spreadsheets at once, create a `.bat` batch file that contains
commands like this for each document:

```
start "" "C:\path\spreadsheet.xlsx"
```

You may create an icon for this batch file on the desktop, then copy/move
it to the taskbar.

To close all open spreadsheets at once with save (if modified),
use the following command, perhaps placed in another `.bat` file:

```
taskkill /im excel*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add a button to the Quick Access toolbar (QAT) in Excel which will Close All open workbooks.
On the QAT, at the right hand end, click on the down arrow. Click "More Commands". This will open the Options dialog box (so you could go to file > options instead).

In the drop down box labelled "Choose commands from", select "Commands not in the Ribbon".

Scroll down to find "Close All" and select it, then click "Add" to add to the QAT. Click OK and you are done.

If you really want the button to be somewhere on the Ribbon instead of the QAT, then in the Options dialog box, choose "Customise Ribbon" in the left hand navigation pane, then follow a similar path to above, but before you click "Add" you need to select the ribbon you want it to be on and add a new group.

As to opening a bunch of files at once, just select them all in Windows Explorer, right click > open and that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

#### Add 'Close All' to your Excel Quick Access Toolbar (QAT)

1. The QAT is at the top left of your Excel window. The rightmost icon there is a little downer-arrow. Click on that:

   [image]

And select 'More Commands...'

2. From the 'Customize the Quick Access Toolbar' menu that comes up:

[image]

Select 'Commands Not in the Ribbon' (or 'All Commands')

3. Scroll down to select 'Close All' and click the <kbd>Add > ></kbd> button to add this command to your ribbon.

[image]

Press OK to save settings.

4. Voila. 'Close All' open Excel windows with a single click.

[image]

#### NB.

1. I already have a few commands on my QAT, so yours won't look exactly like these images.
2. This is in MS Office 2016. Whatever new/newer version you're using will no doubt have something almost if not exactly like this to manage the QAT. If you're not sure, post back with your version and the problem you're having and/or google 'Excel [your version] Quick Access Toolbar'.